# Get value from xpath with flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, xpath

i have a script to get the value from a webpage using xpath, now im convertingf this to python flask and im having some issues here.

This works and uses a webdriver.

```
        xpath_dir = "// *[ @ id = 'kibana-body'] / div[1] / div / div / div[4] / div / ul"
        li_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath_dir)
        # time_elements = li_element.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "time")
        time_elements = li_element.find_elements_by_tag_name("time")
        # message_elements = li_element.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "span.message")
        message_elements = li_element.find_elements_by_tag_name("span.message")
        message_element = message_elements[len(time_elements) - 1]
        msg_string = message_element.text
```

i dont think that since this is flask with python webpage i will need a webdriver so im trying to do this like this

```
    page = requests.get(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    print("page.content: ",page.content)
    xpath_dir = tree.xpath("// *[ @ id = 'kibana-body'] / div[1] / div / div / div[4] / div / ul")

    print("xpath_dir: ",xpath_dir)
    li_element = xpath_dir.find_elements(By.XPATH, tree)
    print("li_element: ",li_element)
    time_elements = xpath_dir.find_elements_by_tag_name("time")
    message_elements = xpath_dir.find_elements_by_tag_name("span.message")
    message_element = message_elements[len(time_elements) - 1]
    msg_string = message_element.text
```

im getting the page.content print with the html of the page and xpath_dir = []

> li_element = tree.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath_dir)Open an interactive
> python shell in this frame
>
> AttributeError: 'HtmlElement' object has no attribute 'find_element'

Is there something im missing?

Comment: Please provide link or part/entire html/xml code.

Comment: Hi, you want the html of the destiny page or the request page? the path is right because this works on app, it just dont work when trying to convert to flask